# Rails: dependent scopes with conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have the following User object with scopes:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :vendors,   lambda { where(:user_type => 'v') }
  scope :customers, lambda { where(:user_type => 'c') }
  ...
```

I'd like to create a new `inactive` scope that behaves differently for vendors vs. customers, e.g. in pseudo code

```
  scope :inactive, lambda {
    if (:user_type => 'v')
      where(some_condition_only_for_vendors)

    elsif (:user_type => 'c')
      where(different_condition_only_for_customers)

    else
      where(another_condition)

    end
  }
```

This way, I can do something like `users.vendors.inactive` to get all inactive vendors based on one set of conditions, and `users.customers.inactive` to get all inactive customers based on another set.

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this? Note that there's a lot of legacy code here, so implementing inheritance may not be feasible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see immediately is that you call a scope from the class, and do not have a record instance to get the user_type.

```
User.inactive
```

So you might have something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :inactive, lambda { |user_type|
    case user_type
    when 'v'
      where(some_condition_only_for_vendors)
    when 'c'
      where(different_condition_only_for_customers)
    else
      where(another_condition)
    end
  }

  def related_users
    User.inactive(user_type).all
  end
end
```